# How to make Safari use the List view not the Column view

Tags: safari

When I use Safari File-->Open File, it uses the Column view.How can I get Safari to use the List view instead?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different!

On macOS Big Sur, click the button shown on the screenshot and pick another view.

[image]

These are the options shown to me:

- Ícones = Icons
- Lista = List
- Colunas = Columns

Edit: alternatively, when you have the window open, you can use the same shortcuts that are also available on Finder: `[command] + [1]`, `[command] + [2]`, `[command] + [3]` to pick the respective options, as Tetsujin mentioned.

Comment: Well, I have done this many times (to set the List view in Finder as the. default). However Safari does not use the lis view it always uses the column view. The strange thing is that on my MackBook Safari uses the List view however not iMac.

Comment: I have the same strange behaviour; Safari unavoidably defaults to Column view in the file picker (Macbook Pro, macOS 12.2.1). This is annoying, because the column view is not sorted by 'Date Added', while my List view is, so I need to switch manually every time I select a file.

Comment: @Isaiah you can change the sort mode of any view, so the Column view can also be changed to sort by date added. On my answer's screenshot, the button to the right side of the one currently selected displays the sort options. You can even see on that screenshot that my Downloads folder uses the Column view, with "Use Groups" enabled and is sorted by Date added (Ontem = Yesterday, Últimos... = Previous 7 days, etc)